# What does the なさいよ in 気をつけなさいよ mean?

Tags: grammar

Had some trouble with the translation. I know that 気をつける means "to be careful" but I had trouble with the なさいよ part.

Comment: Do you know what なさい and よ mean separately?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what they mean separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, we need to split なさい　and よ . They are two different things.

なさい 
polite command/request form of なさる (like ください as a form of くださる) .

[なさる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/163920/meaning/m0u/) is itself 尊敬語 (keigo) for する ...

---

[よ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/226011/meaning/m0u/)

よ is often used at the end of Japanese sentences. Its presence/absence does not normally change the basic meaning. Instead, it marks a variety of nuances depending on whether the speaker is male/female.

Here, I think it means that it's a request.

Comment: So it would be "Please be careful" in polite form?

Comment: yeah pretty much.

Comment: @Joshuap88 Be careful though. It may be polite, but it is used by superiors when speaking to inferiors e.g. parents to children.

Comment: よ to me mostly seems to mean 'I'm telling you this because I think you need to hear it and you won't figure it out on your own'.

Comment: @Sjiveru that was my initial thought but upon looking it up in a dictionary, see def 2 in the link above.

Comment: @virmaior That still feels like a subtype of the main meaning to me, but I could be wrong. I see what you're saying, though.